# How to use subscript operator in boost lambda

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

My following program gives a ton of error, I am trying to use operator[] in a noost lambda expression. Please suggest way of using overloaded operator in lambda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>

using namespace std ;
using namespace boost ;
using namespace boost::lambda ;

using namespace std ;
using namespace boost::assign ;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums ;
    nums += 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ;
    vector<int> flags(11, 0) ;

    cout << "Input Vector : "<<endl ;
    copy(nums.begin(), nums.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")) ;
    cout << endl ;

    for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(),
             if_then(_1%2 == 0, bind(&vector<int>::operator[], var(flags), _1)=1)) ;
    cout << "Flag Vector : "<<endl ;
    copy(flags.begin(), flags.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")) ;
    cout << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int>::operator[]` is overloaded.

```
      reference operator[] (size_type n);
const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const;
```

You cannot take an address of an overloaded function (member or not) except in a limited number of contexts, in which the type of the function is known.

You can use an explicit type conversion to select the right function:

```
boost::lambda::bind((vector<int>::reference (vector<int>::*)(vector<int>::size_type))(&vector<int>::operator[]), var(flags), _1);
```

Looks awful? That's because it is. Use C++11 and its built-in lambda and forget `bind` like a nightmare.